# Angular FormControl date format is not the format i want in json

Tags: angular, format, angular-reactive-forms, datefield

I'm working on an Angular web app. I get data from a ReactiveForm and the problem is that when I get date in form's json value, the format is "YYYY-MM-DD" (Date input format) whereas I want the format "YYYYMMDD"(without -) in my json. I need this format because I send the value in post request to an API.

I have already looking for how to change input format but I didn't find anything.

Can you help me please ?

How I parse my json to fit my form (I need to convert date to input format):

```
this.mapStringToDateInputFormat(dayInformation);

mapStringToDateInputFormat(value: any) {
  const initialDateString: string = value.date;
  const year = initialDateString.substr(0, 4);
  const month = initialDateString.substr(4, 2);
  const day = initialDateString.substr(6, 2);
  value.date = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
}
```

Comment: please provide ur code and which datefield you are using

Answer (score 0):

Use moment in your application it makes easier for your date and time related conversions

install momentjs by npm

```
npm install moment --save
```

In your ts file import it like this and use moment for your conversion related operations

```
import moment from 'moment';


date="2018-08-23"
convrtdDate=moment(this.date).format(''YYYYMMDD'') //20180823
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need this format because I send the value in post request to an API.

well, you need decide with what kind of data do you want to work. And change the service so your component work with this kind of data. e.g. You can has a service with this functions:

```
getData(id)
{
    return this.httpClient(....).pipe(map((x:any)=>{
        x.date=x.date.substr(0, 4)+'-'+x.date.substr(4, 2)+'-'+
               x.datesubstr(6, 2);
        return x
    }))
}
getListData()
{
    return this.httpClient(....).pipe(map((res:any[])=>{
        res.forEach((x:any)=>
        {
           x.date=x.date.substr(0, 4)+'-'+x.date.substr(4, 2)+'-'+
               x.datesubstr(6, 2);
        })
        return res
    })
}

//when you insert/update
insert(data:any)
{
     data.date=data.date.substr(0, 4)+data.date.substr(5, 2)+
               data.datesubstr(8, 2);
     this.http.post(...,data)
}
```

If in future improvements, change the way you received the data, you only need change the service according this change